# How to perform OLS-regression in R with multiple Assets and daily data

Tags: r, time-series, regression, finance

I have the following problem:

I have three dataframes that contain daily market data for pairs of assets. In total there are 54 pairs that are labeled by a PAIR_ID.

Lets say the dataframes are called df1, df2, df3.

All dataframes have the same structure but contain different values:

| Date | P1 | P2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 02.01.2022 | -0,02 | .... |
| 03.01.2022 | 0,05 | .... |

The values are always numerical. The Column Header from the second column on is a unique PAIR_ID.

I want to create a regression Model that does the following:

df1 (value for Pair X on date X) ~ alpha + ß1*df2 (value for Pair X on date X) +ß*df3 (value for Pair X on date X) + error term

I know how to perform OLS Regression with one asset / one pair, but I have no idea how to perform the regression so it takes into account all the pairs with their individual data. I don't want 54 regression with different results but rather one result that tell me about the connection of the variables over the whole sample. How should I structure my data?

Thanks!

So far I only tried to perform regression with every single bond pair but that leads to 54 results which I want to prevent. I would like to receive one result, but unfortunately I have no idea how to get there.

Comment: Do you want to regress each Pair on all others?

Comment: No, the pairs need to be treated separately as I have selected them because they are pretty similar when it comes to certain characteristics. I am interested in the value of the intercept across the whole sample of pairs as it would capture the effect of the attribute that is not covered by the independent variables.